# How to symbolize two variables of a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have uploaded my country map with local level (municipality).
I want to symbolize two variables: province and number of cases for municipalities.
I Graduated number of cases with different color.
Now I want to symbolize (category) by different color.
how can I categorize (province) and (graduate) cases at same shapefile.

Comment: You can use rule-based thematic maps or duplicate the layer and create different thematic maps on the two variables.

Comment: @Zoltan is the correct answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Zoltan thank you very much for answering.